# Export Grid View in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

Export GridView to Excel is working Fine But My problem is when excel open the
file, it became numeric, this may cause problem, cause the field is a credit
card number (e.g 1234567812345678 ), the excel will show 1.23457E+15, and the
actual value became 1234567812345670, that is totally wrong.

Comment: Show me how did you export to Excel !

Comment: this problem is of excel column width if you increase the width then you will see the proper value

Comment: How to increase Width

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use **EPPlus.dll** to export excel sheet..
You get it from [here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/releases/view/89923)..